# Creating a horizontal recycler which updates a vertical recycler

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I really don't know how to describe my problem, but here is an image to show what am talking about[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zgUz.png)

So judging from the image, the horizontal view with months is a recyclerview with the Layoutmanager set in horizontal, so when someone is scrolling through the months it continuously fetches the correct information/filters based on the month at the middle but do not know how to implement

Answer (score 0):

You can implement those months using a view pager, and then implement a fragment for each month. Each fragment will have a recycler view and fragment will fetch the data and feed it into recycler view.

You can refer to this link for an example https://www.journaldev.com/12958/android-tablayout-viewpager

Comment: I thought of that but wouldn't that be a heavy layout? also from what am thinking, the months would have to be deduced from all the records in the database, a viewpager would have to be greated at runtime (that thing shakes a normal phone with 2 to 3 of them) recycler feels lighter

Comment: You can use viewpager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter. It only keeps fixed number of fragents at runtime(+x for both sides where x is choosen by you, i choose 1 generally) and the rest of them are created when required. It wont be much heavy. You can also update the list of months at runtime